# Invocar activities previas sin pasar por método onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una lista de activities (uno, dos, tres y cuatro) las cuales quiero que estén activas en pantalla en un orden aleatorio y se vayan repitiendo, por ejemplo:
dos -> cuatro -> uno -> cuatro -> tres -> etc...

Ahora mismo estoy invocándolas con un startActivity() y cada vez que las invoco pasa por el método onCreate() y crea todas las instancias y datos, cosa que me parece poco efectiva a nivel de rendimiento.

He leído que para pasar a la activity anterior sin pasar por el onCreate() se hace mediante un finish() en la activity actual, pero eso a mi no me sirve ya que no quiero pasar a la anterior, quiero invocar otra que previamente ha sido invocada.

El código que estoy usando para pasar entre las activities es el siguiente:

```java
Button btnRandom = findViewById(R.id.btnRandomActivity);
Class nextActivity = Utils.nextActivity();
btnRandom.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(this, nextActivity)));

public static Class nextActivity() {

    List<Class> activitiesList = Arrays.asList(MainActivity1.class, MainActivity2.class, MainActivity3.class, MainActivity4.class);
    Integer random = (int) (Math.random() * activitiesList.size());
    return activitiesList.get(random);
}
```

¿Cómo podría invocar estas activities sin pasar por el onCreate()?

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que haz hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que haz utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Creo que ese no es el propósito de los Activities. Quizá sea mejor idea usar Fragments.

Comment: @Mateo pero el problema seria el mismo, estaría creando en fragment y pasando por el onCreate cada vez que lo invoco , ¿no?

Comment: @Persifis supongo que sí. Pero con Activities solo puedes iniciar una y si quieres terminar la anterior, pero no "precargarlas". En cambio el fragmento lo puedes crear en cualquier momento. Por qué no lo pruebas y primero? La idea es que funcione, entonces si hace falta optimizas.

Comment: @Mateo lo he intentado con fragments, pero el problema es el mismo, siempre me pasa por el onCreate()

Comment: @Persifis insisto, por qué empeñarse en optimizar desde el principio? Deja la optimización para lo último. Si es necesario puedes perfilar el código y seguramente haya otras secciones que querrás optimizar antes. Y sí, es natural que pasen por la función `onCreate` porque así es el ciclo de vida del [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle). Creo que en todo el ciclo de vida `onCreate` de un mismo Fragmento solo es llamado una vez.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas invocar actividades que previamente abriste, simplemente no uses `finish()` después de invocar cada nueva actividad, esto para que las `Activity` no se destruyan y al llamarlas nuevamente mediante un intent se abran sin que sea llamado nuevamente el método `onCreate()`, sin embargo esto no puede ser una solución real a el problema ya que tu dispositivo puede requerir memoria y en algún momento puede destruirse la `Activity`, al llamarse nuevamente tendría que pasar por onCreate().

Si no deseas llamar `onCreate()`, la solución debería ser hacer uso de Fragments, en este caso no
También podrías hacer uso de Fragments, guardando los Fragments  en la pila `.addToBackStack()` :

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentA");
...
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentB");
...
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentC");
...
```

y posteriormente realizar un `"POP"` para obtener el fragmento que previamente cargaste en la pila.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack ("fragmentB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: ¿Me podrias poner un ejemplo mas en detalle? Soy un poco novata en android y mas con fargments y no termino de entender bien como como iria tu explicación, meto los fragmetns en el stack pero no se sacarlos de ello, nose como usar el POP.